# USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP Docusign Nodejs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign API with a nodejs server. I just recently promoted my sandbox integration key to production "live" and have updated my account ID, Client ID, etc so I hit the production account however, whenever I try to create an envelope, I get this error:

```
    text: '{\r\n  "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP",\r\n  "message": "The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account."\r\n}',
```

I only have 1 user in the prod account so I'm not sure why this user would not have a valid membership. What's the best way to go about debugging this type of issue?

Comment: check in the code if you are passing AccessToken or credentials for PROD UserId or for Demo UserId

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing here was that I wasn't setting the oauthpath correctly. I'm using the nodejs api and you should use apiClient.setOAuthBasePath() to set it. 
If you don't set it, it will default to the demo url. Just in case this helps anyone else.